# Ion-slides slidesPerView property

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-slides

I'm using ion-slides as the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <h6 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="category.name"></h6>
    <ion-slides [loop]="true" [pager]="true" [slidesPerView]="3">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of category.products">
            <img [src]="product.image" class="slide-image">
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'slidesPerView' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-slides'.

1. If 'ion-slides' is an Angular component and it has 'slidesPerView' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-slides' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   ("h6 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="category.name">
   ][slidesPerView]="3">

<img [src]="product"): MainPage@12:43 ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ....

can anyone help please.

ionic -v
2.2.1

cordova -v
6.5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently there was some changes in ion-slides. Make sure you have the latest ionic version (2.0.0).
Also you can use slidesPerView without enclosing it in square brackets as follows

```
<ion-slides pager loop slidesPerView="3">
  <ion-slide>
     ...
  </ion-slide>
<ion-slides>
```

Comment: it's not working

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-slides loop pager slidesPerView="3">
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 4</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 5</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 6</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <h1>Slide 7</h1>
  </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>

</ion-content>

still shows one slide at a time